# Pinging nodes in Network

Tags: scripting, ubuntu, network-programming, ping

I have a network consisting nodes(computers, with ubuntu) with 1 node as root. I am building a fault management system for it, for which, lets say root sends IP address of a node A to node B(through sockets).

Now node B has to ping node A repeatedly to check the network. How should I do this. I mean is there a way to write C/C++ program which given an IP address pings the node and report the problem. Or do I have to write some script or anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Perl and the [Net::Ping](http://search.cpan.org/~smpeters/Net-Ping-2.36/lib/Net/Ping.pm) module, a short script could do this. Or use something like [Big Sister](http://www.bigsister.ch/bigsister.html) for network monitoring.